# How to find out what version of Delphi a component was introduced?

Tags: delphi, history

I'm just now getting around to working with ActionMainMenuBar and ActionManager and I'd like to find out what version of Delphi this component was introduced? Where can I find out this type of information?

Comment: by looking at the code =)

Comment: It was either Delphi 6 or Delphi 7, IIRC.

Comment: @EL has it. Look in the source code.

Comment: @David: It is not perfectly clear exactly where you should look.

Comment: I did look at the source code. All the files say "Copyright(c) 1995-2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc."

Comment: @Andreas look in source code for version n, where it is not present, and version n+1 where it is present.

Comment: @David: Yeah, but at least I don't have access to every version of the source code...

Comment: There is no way, really, other than either having all the versions and checking, or searching on Google for each of the "What's new in....." articles.

Comment: @David Heffernan, so show it. And not the "Copyright(c) 1995-20..." part. =)

Comment: @David Heffernan, component's code, of cource. part of it. If it's not compiled =)

Comment: @EL Why? I'm not interested. I just agreed with you. Namely that the answer can be found in the source.

Comment: @David Heffernan, sorry. All the time I thought that you are the author of this question. I am sorry =)

Comment: @Cape Cod Gunny, show us any part of source code of this component if it's not compiled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Source 1**

I found this page with a Google search: http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorCon2003/Actions/6102.htm

Under the **Introduction** section near the top it mentions that actions and action list components have been around since "Delphi 4 in June 1998"

The TActionMainMenuBar seems to have been introduced in 2001 with Delphi 6:

Under the **Action Managers And ActionBands** section about a quarter of the page down:

"If you are using Delphi 6 or later, you can dispense with action list components altogether and simply use an action manager, which allows you to create action components.

The new action components are sat at the end of the Additional page of the Component Palette. The TActionManager component is the enhanced action list replacement which we will use here. You can also find the two Action Band components, TActionMainMenuBar and TActionToolBar."

---

**Source 2**

From the Embarcadero Developer Network I managed to also find this page here which shows screen shots from Delphi 6: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27317

[image]

A quote from that link:

"Without further ado, we dive straight into the component palette of Delphi 6.

On the Additional tab you'll notice some new stuff, such as TValueListEditor, TLabeledEdit, TColorBox, TActionManager, TActionMainMenuBar, TActionToolBar, and TCustomizeDlg."

Comment: This answer mostly answers the example instead of directly addressing the question. Reading between the lines, the answer appears to be that to find out when a component was introduced to Delphi, you should search in the hope of finding contemporary documents mentioning the components and how they're new.